# What is this pictured Lenovo (multilingual?) keyboard layout and how to use keys on the row below the function keys?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am planning to get myself a new keyboard and thinking of this one (see pic) as it has extra keys I use frequently. But what is the layout/map called and how to use the keys in the row below the function key row? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: When there's a "£" it usually mean English UK.

Comment: It's swedish layout with Å and other characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very very close to a [Norwegian keyboard](http://www.farah.cl/Keyboardery/A-Visual-Comparison-of-Different-National-Layouts/#no).

Comment: But I still do not know how use the three rows under the function key rows on Windows 10.

Comment: If memory serves - you would use altGR key for those https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key